How to insert list of words from function in #list function in typst?
I made this function which can create a list of words:
#let bullet(list_bullet)={
  let number=0
  for content in list_bullet {
  number=number+1
  if number == list_bullet.len() {
     [[#content .]]
     break 
     }
  [[#content ;], ]
  }
}

#let example = ("Hello","Word")
#bullet(example)
==> [Hello;],[Word.]

I would like to insert this result in #list function but its not working ...
#list(marker: [#text(rgb(0,158,161))[#sym.circle.filled]], spacing : 8pt, indent : 12pt, bullet(example))

I have this result:
 - [Hello ;], [Word .]

And I would like :
 - Hello;
 - Word.

I would like to know which differences Typste made between:
#list(marker: [#text(rgb(0,158,161))[#sym.circle.filled]], spacing : 8pt, indent : 12pt, bullet(example)) 

And:
#list(marker: [#text(rgb(0,158,161))[#sym.circle.filled]], spacing : 8pt, indent : 12pt,[Hello;],
[Word.]) 

Is working.

In your code, bullet doesn't return an array of content:
#let example = ("Hello", "Word")

#repr(bullet(example))

#repr(([Hello;], [Word.]))


The list needs an array of content (or string) to render, and I would use code like this:
#let bullet_next(list_bullet) = {
  list_bullet
    .enumerate()
    .map(item => {
      if item.first() != list_bullet.len() - 1 {
        item.last() + ";"
      } else {
        item.last() + "."
      }
    })
}

#bullet_next(example)

#repr(bullet_next(example))

#list(
  marker: [#text(rgb(0, 158, 161))[#sym.circle.filled]],
  spacing: 8pt,
  indent: 12pt,
  ..bullet_next(example),
)

And the result is:

The code maps items to (index, item), then transforms the tuple into a string. You can also use text, block, and so on as the return content:
#let bullet_next(list_bullet) = {
  list_bullet
    .enumerate()
    .map(item => {
      if item.first() != list_bullet.len() - 1 {
        block(stroke: 1pt, inset: 2pt, item.last() + ";")
      } else {
        item.last() + "."
      }
    })
}

#bullet_next(example)

#repr(bullet_next(example))

#list(
  marker: [#text(rgb(0, 158, 161))[#sym.circle.filled]],
  spacing: 8pt,
  indent: 12pt,
  ..bullet_next(example),
)


